# Android JSON parser sends multiple copies of data to server

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

In my application there is registration screen which sends takes registration details from the user and sends them to server and then the server stores it in the database.

My problem is that, when i checked the database, there are multiple copies of data. I don't know whether the multiples copies are created by client side or server side.

I have added the screenshot of the database and you can see clearly there are multiple copies of same data. Every time i press send button on the client side in my android application, two of same data are stored in the database. I haven't used any loops still it is storing two copies of same data in the data base.

here is my code

```
public class RegisterScreen extends Activity {

    Button reg;
    TextView tv;
    EditText fn,ln,un,pwd,mob,email;
    HttpPost httppost;
    StringBuffer buffer;
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpClient httpclient;
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        reg=(Button)findViewById(R.id.reg);
        fn=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.fn);
        ln=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ln);
        un=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.un);
        pwd=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.pwd);
        mob=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mob);
        email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);


        reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(RegisterScreen.this, "",
                        "Registering user...", true);
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        login();
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });
    }


    void login(){
        try{

            httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost= new HttpPost("http://192.168.43.6/test/registration.php"); // make sure the url is correct.
            //add your data
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar,
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstname",fn.getText().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastname",ln.getText().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",un.getText().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",pwd.getText().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mob",mob.getText().toString().trim()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",email.getText().toString().trim()));// $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            //Execute HTTP Post Request
            response=httpclient.execute(httppost);

            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
            System.out.println("Response : " + response);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + response);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("Registration")){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterScreen.this,"Registration Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                startActivity(new Intent(RegisterScreen.this, LoginScreen.class));
            }else{
                showAlert();
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            dialog.dismiss();
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public void showAlert(){
        RegisterScreen.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterScreen.this);
                builder.setTitle("Registration Error.");
                builder.setMessage("Problem in Registration. Please try again later")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

here is my server side code

```
<?php
$hostname_localhost ="localhost";
$database_localhost ="testdb";
$username_localhost ="root";
$password_localhost ="";
$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);

$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$mob = $_POST['mob'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$query_search = "INSERT INTO register(Firstname, Lastname, loginname, pwd, Mobilenumber , emailid) VALUES('$firstname', '$lastname','$username','$password','$mob','$email')";
$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());
//$rows = mysql_num_rows($query_exec);
//echo $rows;
 echo "Registration";
?>
```

here is screenshot of the database[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your calling execute twice in `Login()`?

```
response=httpclient.execute(httppost);

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
```

Comment: you answer worked perfectly. I did remove response=httpclient.execute(httppost);. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know whether the multiples copies are created by client side
>   or server side.

This code inserting a new row every time it's run

```
$query_search = "INSERT INTO register(Firstname, Lastname, loginname, pwd, Mobilenumber , emailid) VALUES('$firstname', '$lastname','$username','$password','$mob','$email')";
$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());
```

You need to select for existing data and only then insert a row

Comment: sorry but i didn't get your answer. Can you please explain it more deeply??

Comment: First you need to choose a field which must be unique, for example an email. 
Then run a query "SELECT 1 FROM `register` WHERE `emailid` = '$email'".
If the row don't exists, run INSERT query

Comment: i am sending data from android application to php server so that it can store it in database and not retrieve it. It just have to store it in database and nothing else. The problem is that it is storing multiple copies of the data. Your solution would work if i was trying to retrieve the data and not store it

Comment: You don't retrieve it, just checking if row exists.
Another way u can make an email field unique by a mysql
ALTER TABLE `register` ADD UNIQUE (`emailid` )

Comment: You solution doesn't make any sense. I am storing value in the database then why do i need to alter the database and use select query?? Even if i remove all the contents(all rows) inside the database, and then insert fresh new data, still two copies of each data is store. Any suggest about it??